# Python convert to gmt

Tags: python-3.x, time

I am getting incorrect date output.
The date should be Febraruy 2, 2018 12:00:00 AM instead the date is February 1, 2018 7:00:00

```
import datetime
a = 17564*86400
# a prints 1517529600
a = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# a prints 2018-02-01 19:00:00
```

It should print 2018-02-02 12:00:00 AM
I am trying to get into gmt time.

If you visit https://www.epochconverter.com and paste 1517529600 into the timestamp to human date. You will see my issue.

Comment: Why do you expect that result and what timezone is your locale set to?

Comment: Assuming that the timestamp is in UTC, try with [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp). Otherwise you'll have to provide the correct timezone of your timestamp to the `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` function.

Comment: fromtimestamp will use your local time zone the machine is set too. Read this docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html and see what gmtime() does or tzinfo.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
a = 17564*86400
a = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a,datetime.timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
prints 2018-02-02 00:00:00
```

By adding datetime.timezone.utc sets the timezone to utc/gmt.

This would also work, they both do the same.

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
a = 17564*86400
a = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a, timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.